# Creating Random Checkboxes Programmatically

Tags: android, checkbox, onclicklistener

I am developing an application in which i am making a form on server response, the response consist of radio buttons checkboxes which i create programaticaly, the problem is if there is more then one check box then i can not differentiate which checkbox is checked in listener. any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Try to given different id to each CheckBox.

Comment: How to give different ids because its random from server may be 3 may be 4. and then how i wil get these ids in listener

Comment: Add a tag to each checkbox when you create it and in the listener just get the tag so you know which one it is.

Comment: How to given different id is depends on you and for getting this ids in listener then you have to implement checked change listener u get selected check box id there.

Comment: Thanx for your help  glm9637 and  Haresh Chhelana, I did the job, now what I will do for radiogroups.